# Understanding the Handler in ListActivity

Tags: android, handler, listactivity

I'm looking at the `ListActivity` source code, and I'm seeing that a private `Handler` is being defined, and that a `Runnable` is posted to this handler in the `onContentChanged()` method.

I don't quite get the point of this, as the handlers, as I understand it, are there for inter-thread communication. Here, the definition of the handler and the posting is happening on the same thread, and no delay is specified in the post() call. I can't see the handler being used for anything else, either.

I've probably misunderstood something about the use of handlers here. Why is it done the way it is here, and not by just running `mList.focusableViewAvailable()` (the call inside the runnable) directly? Wouldn't the result be the same?

Beneath is what I believe are the relevant portions of the `ListActivity` source code:

```
public class ListActivity extends Activity {

    protected ListView mList;

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    private Runnable mRequestFocus = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            mList.focusableViewAvailable(mList);
        }
    };

    /**
     * Updates the screen state (current list and other views) when the
     * content changes.
     *
     * @see Activity#onContentChanged()
     */
    @Override
    public void onContentChanged() {
        super.onContentChanged();
        View emptyView = findViewById(com.android.internal.R.id.empty);
        mList = (ListView)findViewById(com.android.internal.R.id.list);
        if (mList == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                    "Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is " +
                    "'android.R.id.list'");
        }
        if (emptyView != null) {
            mList.setEmptyView(emptyView);
        }
        mList.setOnItemClickListener(mOnClickListener);
        if (mFinishedStart) {
            setListAdapter(mAdapter);
        }
        mHandler.post(mRequestFocus);
        mFinishedStart = true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Ugh, your going to give me NIGHTMARES! I've seen that `RuntimeException` too often when I was trying to learn how to use a `ListActivity`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is it done the way it is here, and not by just running mList.focusableViewAvailable() (the call inside the runnable) directly? Wouldn't the result be the same?

Your concern should not be the `Handler`. Your concern should be the call to `post()`. A `Handler` is not even really needed, as `post()` is available on `View` -- this code may pre-date that, though.

`post()` takes a `Runnable` and puts it on the message queue for the main application thread. As such, it will not get processed until all other messages that are presently on that queue get processed (FIFO). Presumably, `ListActivity` needs some other message on the queue to be processed first before `focusableViewAvailable()` will work successfully.

Comment: So since the ListActivity will always run on the main application thread (I assume), the instantiation of the Handler in this case would always hook into that thread anyway? In that case, I suppose all of this could also be replaced with a call to runOnUiThread()?

Comment: @rogerkk: "So since the ListActivity will always run on the main application thread (I assume), the instantiation of the Handler in this case would always hook into that thread anyway?" -- yes to both. "In that case, I suppose all of this could also be replaced with a call to runOnUiThread()?" -- either `runOnUiThread()` or `post()` called on, say, the `ListView` would work equally well.